# Webpage I designed localy is on a remote server but redirects to local server

Tags: php, html, yii2

Im still new in many regards and hope someone can help me with my problem.

I programmed a web page on my localhost with the advanced template of `yii2`. On localhost it is running quiet ok. When I copy the whole content to a remote server and try to open it up (via https://remoteurl.com), I land on my localhost again.
Is there a config file I have to adapt?

I already checked my config files in `/frontend/, /common/ and /backend/` and cant find any redirecting.

Also in my `index.html` there was this code but I put in

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://192.168.77.199/advanced/frontend/web/">
```

but I changed that to

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://remoteURL.com/advanced/frontend/web/">
```

Still when I try to open the url it redirects me to the local server.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you look for `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` in the entire project to see if the code is somewhere there. There might be a billion reasons why you get a wrong redirection(htaccess, leftover-code, rewrite-rules, cache[browser or server], and many more). I would suggest start debugging when do you get redirected and what code is executed before that point. I would also suggest you do not rely on HTML for redirects. You can use `return $this->redirect()` in the controller or `header("Location: /");die;` in the views.